# Removing duplicates on a variable without sorting

Tags: bash, unix, shell, sorting, variables

I have a variable that contains the following space separated entries.

```
variable="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"
```

How do I remove the duplicates without sorting?

```
#Something like this.
new_variable="apple lemon papaya avocado grapes mango banana"
```

I have found somewhere a script that accomplish removing the duplicates of a variable, but does sort the contents.

```
#Not something like this.
new_variable=$(echo "$variable"|tr " " "\n"|sort|uniq|tr "\n" " ")
echo $new_variable
apple avocado banana grapes lemon mango papaya
```

Answer (score 22):

```
new_variable=$( awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "}!a[$0]++' <<<$variable );
```

Here's how it works:

RS (Input Record Separator) is set to a white space so that it treats each fruit in $variable as a record instead of a field.  The non-sorting unique magic happens with !a[$0]++.  Since awk supports associative arrays, it uses the current record ($0) as the key to the array a[]. If that key has not been seen before, a[$0] evaluates to '0' (awk's default value for unset indices) which is then negated to return TRUE. I then exploit the fact that awk will default to 'print $0' if an expression returns TRUE and no '{ commands }' are given. Finally, a[$0] is then incremented such that this key can no longer return TRUE and thus repeat values are never printed.  ORS (Output Record Separator) is set to a space as well to mimic the input format.

A less terse version of this command which produces the same output would be the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "}{ if (a[$0] == 0){ a[$0] += 1; print $0}}'
```

Gotta love awk =)

*EDIT*

If you needed to do this in pure Bash 2.1+, I would suggest this:

```
#!/bin/bash    

variable="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"
temp="$variable"

new_variable="${temp%% *}"

while [[ "$temp" != ${new_variable##* } ]]; do
   temp=${temp//${temp%% *} /}
   new_variable="$new_variable ${temp%% *}"
done

echo $new_variable;
```

Comment: Simply testing for membership is better than counting:

    awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} { if (!($0 in a)) { a[$0]; print } }'

Or more tersely:

    awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} !($0 in a || a[$0])'

Comment: @Mark: Doing a 'time' over a loop of 10,000 iterations shows that yours is just over 3% slower. Not very much but nonetheless, not better.  This difference will only become larger as the number of elements grows since your version takes O(n) time while mine is always a constant O(1).

Comment: Really nice solution, thanks. Except if duplicates are found at the end, one after the other then it doesn't work. Ex: variable="apple lemon papaya papaya" prints: apple lemon papaya papaya. Whereas if I have: variable="apple lemon papaya papaya mango" then it removes the duplicate papaya and prints: apple lemon papaya mango. Thoughts?

Comment: Found the following solution which helped with the problem outlined in my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185241/removing-duplicates-in-bash-string-using-awk?noredirect=1&lq=1 Thank you for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 6):

This pipeline version works by preserving the original order:

```
variable=$(echo "$variable" | tr ' ' '\n' | nl | sort -u -k2 | sort -n | cut -f2-)
```

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me.  The awk solution still had duplicates.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash:

```
variable="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"

declare new_value=''

for item in $variable; do
  if [[ ! $new_value =~ $item ]] ; then   # first time?
    new_value="$new_value $item"
  fi
done
new_value=${new_value:1}                  # remove leading blank
```

Comment: Good solution, but note that this locks you into Bash 3.X due to the '=~' operator.

Answer (score 3):

In pure, portable `sh`:

```
words="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"
seen=
for word in $words; do
  case $seen in
    $word\ * | *\ $word | *\ $word\ * | $word) 
      # already seen
      ;;
    *)
      seen="$seen $word"
      ;;
  esac
done
echo $seen
```

Answer (score 1):

shell

```
declare -a arr
variable="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"
set -- $variable
count=0
for c in $@
do
    flag=0
    for((i=0;i<=${#arr[@]}-1;i++))
    do
        if [ "${arr[$i]}" == "$c" ] ;then
            flag=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if  [ "$flag" -eq 0 ] ; then
        arr[$count]="$c"
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
done
for((i=0;i<=${#arr[@]}-1;i++))
do
   echo "result: ${arr[$i]}"
done
```

Result when run:

```
linux# ./myscript.sh
result: apple
result: lemon
result: papaya
result: avocado
result: grapes
result: mango
result: banana
```

OR if you want to use gawk

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} (!($0 in a) ){a[$0];print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Z Shell:

```
% variable="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"
% print ${(zu)variable}                                                               
apple lemon papaya avocado grapes mango banana
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable="apple lemon papaya avocado lemon grapes papaya apple avocado mango banana"
variable=$(printf '%s\n' "$variable" | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '!a[$0]++{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}')
variable="${variable%,*}"
echo "$variable"
```

Output:

```
apple lemon papaya avocado grapes mango banana
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

`perl -le 'for (@ARGV){ $h{$_}++ }; for (keys %h){ print $_ }' $variable`

`@ARGV` is the list of input parameters from `$variable`
Loop through the list, populating the `h` hash with the loop variable `$_`
Loop through the keys of the `h` hash, and print each one

```
grapes
avocado
apple
lemon
banana
mango
papaya
```

---

This variation prints the output sorted first by frequency `$h{$a} <=> $h{$b}` 
and then alphabetically `$a cmp $b`

`perl -le 'for (@ARGV){ $h{$_}++ }; for (sort { $h{$a} <=> $h{$b} || $a cmp $b } keys %h){ print "$h{$_}\t$_" }' $variable`

```
1       banana
1       grapes
1       mango
2       apple
2       avocado
2       lemon
2       papaya
```

---

This variation produces the same output as the last one.
However, instead of an input shell variable, uses an input file 'fruits', with one fruit per line:

`perl -lne '$h{$_}++; END{ for (sort { $h{$a} <=> $h{$b} || $a cmp $b } keys %h){ print "$h{$_}\t$_" } }' fruits`