# Awk pattern always matches last record?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, gawk

I'm in the process of switching from zsh to bash, and I need to produce a bash script that can remove duplicate entries in `$PATH` without reordering the entries (thus no `sort -d` magic). zsh has some nice array handling shortcuts that made it easy to do this efficiently, but I'm not aware of such shortcuts in bash. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872842/2437315) which has gotten me 90% of the way there, but there is a small problem that I would like to understand better. It appears that when I run that awk command, the last record processed incorrectly matches the pattern.

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=":"}!a[$0]++' <<<"aa:bb:cc:aa:bb:cc"
aa:bb:cc:cc
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=":"}!a[$0]++' <<<"aa:bb:cc:aa:bb"
aa:bb:cc:bb
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=":"}!a[$0]++' <<<"aa:bb:cc:aa:bb:cc:" # note trailing colon
aa:bb:cc:
```

I don't understand awk well enough to know why it behaves this way, but I have managed to work around the issue by using an intermediate array like so.

```bash
array=($(awk 'BEGIN{RS=":";ORS=" "}!a[$0]++' <<<"aa:bb:cc:aa:bb:cc:"))
# Use a subshell to avoid modifying $IFS in current context
echo $(export IFS=":"; echo "${array[*]}")
aa:bb:cc
```

This seems like a sub-optimal solution however, so my question is: did I do something wrong in the awk command that is causing false positive matches on the final record processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last record in your original string is `cc\n` which is different from `cc`. When unsure what's happening in any program in any language, adding some print statements is step 1 to debugging/investigating:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=":"} {print "<"$0">"}' <<<"aa:bb:cc:aa:bb:cc"
<aa>:<bb>:<cc>:<aa>:<bb>:<cc
>:$
```

If you want the RS to be `:` or `\n` then just state that (with GNU awk at least):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[:\n]"; ORS=":"} !a[$0]++' <<<"aa:bb:cc:aa:bb:cc"
aa:bb:cc:$
```

The `$` in all of the above is my prompt.

Comment: Good example to see what's happening. But could you explain why a new line has been appended to the string?

Comment: That's something bash is doing, it essentially makes `cmd <<<"string"` behave the same as `echo "string" | cmd` but without the extra command (`echo`) and the pipe. POSIX text processing tools (sed, awk, grep, etc.) are only guaranteed to work on POSIX text files otherwise you get undefined behavior, so if a file or input stream doesn't end with a newline then it's not a POSIX text file/stream so that trailing newline is necessary to produce expected/desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I now have a better understanding of why the problem occurs, which brings me closer to crafting a proper solution to the problem. As small a problem as this may have been, your answer was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround instead of your bash array solution

```
$ echo "aa:bb:cc:aa:bb:cc" | tr ':' '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++' | paste -sd:
aa:bb:cc
```